# C# And RDLC report break page with Condition

Tags: c#, rdlc

I need to use page break with a specific condition. For example,

I have rdlc report, and i want to add expression that make the pages

breaks when **text value = "@@@@".**

And thanks a lot.

```
=Iif(Fields!anly.Value="@@@@",?? break page code ??, false)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you actually can do that. However it might be possible to add a grouping with a condition that will act as a page break.

Comment: @JimAho is right and it is a good suggestion. it achieves exactly what's needed - page break with condition.

Comment: @InitK Added that as an answer since it was more people (you) than me thinking in those directions.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to add a grouping with a condition that will act as a page break.